# Securing a mobile rest api (Invoked from Mobile APP)

Tags: web-services, rest, security, mobile, captcha

I am designing a REST API that takes a card number and CVV and uses that to check the card balance and other details. We have the HMAC encryption, Device Identifier recognition and SSL header validations and all that security in place.

However the issue is the call is going to be invoked from Mobile app which can be easily reverse engineered to get the code. Once some one has the code they can write a bot to fish (Brute Force) for the legit card number cvv combination.

So in order to lock down the API I am planning to use a captcha (mobile friendly) like FUNCaptcha. However Apps DEV rejected it saying webviews (IOS, Android) are not safe and can be exploited using MITM attacks etc since it is JavaScript based.

Can someone give me some ideas on how to tackle the problem. I need to secure the API from BOT, other automated processes. The only way to do it is via a captcha. but it seems on mobile devices the webview is a bad idea.

Comment: Do you have any authentication mechanism on your backend ?

Comment: Is it feasible to just limit a client (IP address) to `x` calls per minute or hour to that specific API call?

Comment: We don't have a username,password however we have device identifier to make sure that the call is from a valid client. there is no other authentication mechanism for this unfortunately(it is an old code).

we can defintely limit based on IP and Device identifier, i am just trying to find the best possible solution. The Ip fails when u have a distributed attack on the API.